# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT: Formatting the output

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT usrFirst, usrLast) as receiver_name  //etc
```

When using PHP, it outputs my list of names as follows:

```
<?php 
    echo $row['receiver_name'];

    //Outputs: JohnDoe,BillSmith,DaveJones

    //Desired output: John Doe, Bill Smith, and Dave Jones
```

I need help figuring out three things:

1. How can I put a space between the first and last name?
2. How can insert a space after each comma?
3. How can I add an 'and' right before the last name displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you should bully MySQL into doing exactly what you want there. I'd suggest using the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(first, ' ', last) AS receiver_name
FROM names;
```

Then loop through this resultset in PHP and handle the case of ' and ' there.

If performance is a concern (you'll be doing this query often). You would benefit from not using DISTINCT on the calculated value of CONCAT(first, ' ', last) as that would require the use of a temporary table.

To tweak it, add the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE names ADD INDEX (last, first);
```

And change your query as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ', last) AS receiver_name
FROM names
GROUP BY last, first;
```

You'll be able to get your values directly from the index without resorting to a temporary table or filesort.

As far as the loop goes, something like the following would work:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli(/* connection info */);

$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ', last) AS receiver_name "
     . 'FROM names '
     . 'GROUP BY last, first';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

    $string = '';
    $count = $result->num_rows;
    $rows = $result->fetch_all();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {
        $string .= $rows[$i][0] . ', ';
    }
    $string .= ' and ' . $rows[$i][0];
    echo $string; // John Smith, Bob Dole, and George Bush
}
```

**Note** This code assumes you would always have at least 2 rows returned. I'm sure you can figure out how to handle the case of only a single name returned. :)

Comment: Thanks hobodave.  Could you perhaps shed a bit of light on how to do the php loop?  Or point me in the direction of a resource.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', usrFirst, usrLast)) as receiver_name
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT usr_first, usr_last
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
```

This solution will distinguish between `'Smith, John Davis'` and `'Davis Smith, John'` (will return `'John Davis Smith'` twice, not once, since they are different people).

Comment: Does the last letter `q` in your code have any special meaning?

Comment: @Adam: no, that's a nested query alias. You can make it `p` or any other identifier you like.