# Modifying CONCAT display

Tags: php, mysql

I just learned how to use the CONCAT function in a database query. It works great, but I'm trying to figure out how to modify the display.

In my reference table, I have displays that look like this: Japan,Arizona

I'd like to insert a space after the comma and display the names alphabetically, like this:

Arizona, Japan

I inserted a secondary order command at the end of my query, but it doesn't do anything. Also, is it possible to insert hyperlinks in individual names in a CONCAT string? For example:

```
<a href="/world/arizona" title="Arizona">Arizona</a>, <a href="/world/japan" title="Japan">Japan</a>
```

Below is my query...

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Group1, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1,
 GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GROUP_CONCAT(GG.Name) as Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
WHERE PLAN.Group1 = :RefCat AND Rank != '55'
GROUP BY PLAN.Common
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213389/mysql-group-concat-question-probably-simple

Comment: Don't generate html at the database level. That's a client-side thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) takes optional arguments of `order by` and `separator`, so:

```
SELECT    PLAN.Latin Latin2, 
          PLAN.Common, 
          PLAN.Group1, 
          PLAN.Rank, 
          PLAN.Family, 
          PLAN.Order1,
          GS.Symbol, 
          GS.Latin, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(GG.Name ORDER BY GG.Name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as Names, 
          GG.IDParent
FROM      gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
WHERE     PLAN.Group1 = :RefCat AND Rank != '55'
GROUP BY  PLAN.Common
ORDER BY  PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have PHP tagged, let's solve it with PHP.

- Grab the results from the database table.
- Explode the `,`, creating an array of `GG.Name`'s.
- Sort the array alphabetically.

```
 //Grab results and store in an assoc array
 
 $arrNames = explode(",", $arrResults['Names']);
 natsort($arrNames);
```

For example, we have the following array;

```
 array("Japan", "Arizona", "Hong Kong", "Australia")
```

And we use [natsort](https://www.php.net/natsort)

```
(
    [1] => Arizona
    [3] => Australia
    [2] => Hong Kong
    [0] => Japan
)
```

Comment: @ hd. I chose Mureinik's response as the best answer because it's so simple to implement. However, I suspect your solution may actually be more versatile - for inserting hyperlinks, for example.

Comment: Sure, no problem :) Two ways to solve the same problem. On Mureinik's answer, can you press the green tick to accept it as an answer, so anyone else can see that his one solved your question?